# Is it better to add two numbers to a new variable or adding them together while displaying?

Tags: c++

Which is better:

```cpp
int sum = a + b;
std::cout << sum;
```

```cpp
std::cout << a + b;
```

In terms of performance and efficiency?

Comment: In terms of performance and efficiency *for optimized code* it is likely they'll be identical.  I highly recommend writing your code for *readability* first and foremost unless-and-until **profiling** shows that there is a performance issue.

Comment: Around 99.999999% of the time is spent printing the value. And unless you use `sum` for something else as well, a decent compiler will generate the same code for both.

Comment: Unless you have some other nefarious purpose for `sum` *besides* the output, the only reason to prefer the former over the latter is someone's pure opinion of readability. You'll find any half-baked optimizer worth the silicon it's printed on will [generate the same code for both](https://godbolt.org/z/YvW9Wqzx7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is it better two add two numbers to a new variable

No, it's not better in general.

> or adding them together while displaying?

No, it's not better in general.

Either is usually fine. The intermediate local variable has advantages such as ability to give an understandable name, and it reduces the complexity of individual expressions. But adding a variable increases the total number of names which is another form of complexity. It's a matter of finding a good balance, and the "bestness" is subjective.

> In terms of performance and efficiency?

Not using a local variable is pretty much never more efficient than using a variable. But there is no difference in the shown example. Furthermore, there is no difference in most simple cases.

The difference - if any - is primarily in readability.

Consider another example where you use the result of the operation multiple times. In that case, it would be rare for a program that repeats an operation to be more efficient than another program that stores the result in a variable. But there's still no difference if the case is simple.

Comment: IMHO, I prefer the adding before the output.  This allows me to place a breakpoint at the output statement and verifying the values, before they are output (or another function called).  This is useful in debugging embedded systems or other applications where the output may take a long time or have timing issues (such as logging).